# Allowing Enter in hotkey control

Tags: c++, winapi, common-controls

I'm using the standard hotkey control to allow user to specify a key combination for a certain action. However, it doesn't allow using the Return (Enter) key. Is there a way to allow it? My action is sort-of chat reply, so having a hotkey like Alt+Enter makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to sub-class the control, since by default it rejects keys like `VK_RETURN`.

Your sub-class would probably need to do two things:

- Handle the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message and return `DLGC_WANTMESSAGE` when the message indicates the enter key has been pressed
- Handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` message when return is pressed, and manually set the hotkey in the control by sending it a `HKM_SETHOTKEY` message.